# Dual Booting Garuda Linux on Windows10

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot

I have download the torrent file of garuda linux(Garuda KDE Dr460nized). While installing the Linux I am getting an error, shown below:

[image]

I have created the partition from the original C drive of 97 GB and have kept it unallocated.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Please don't post images if it can be avoided. In your case, you could just type the text shown on the screen. This has numerous advantages, including search engines finding your question and people with visual impairments being able to help. Having said that, you do know that Garuda strongly discourages multi-boot with Windows? Also, it's not clear if you performed any steps before you reached this stage. Finally, Garuda doesn't seem to "see" the partition you created. Please document what you did before the error, and your disk layout, e.g. using the Windows disk administration tool.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/tutorial-for-dual-boot-garuda-linux-windows-10/3884 ?